# SQLITE Query from two different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

I have two tables in my database, `Recipes Table` and `Ingredients Table`.

The database looks like this:

```
Recipes Table:
   recipe_id
   recipe_name

Ingredients Table:
   ingredient_id
   recipe_id
   ingredient_name
```

These tables are connected by `recipe_id`.

The function I'm developing allows the user to select **up to** four ingredients and all the recipes that contain those ingredients will be displayed.

The query I want to make goes like:

```
Get all the recipes that contain ingredients pork, pepper, tomato, salt.
```

The query should return only the recipes that contain **all** the ingredients.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I know how to JOIN tables but fails to create a query that will provide the results I want. At this point, I'm kind of looking for a direct answer and not a suggestion on how to do it myself. Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of joins?

Comment: @SMA I'm familiar with those, but I just can't come up with the right query.

Comment: Your tags are somewhat confusing - are you using SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt It's SQLITE like what's in the title.

Comment: @JhensonMedrano You're missing my point. You *tagged* the question with MySQL and SQLite, whereas your question is *only* about SQLite. So please refrain from using tags that are not relevant for your question (I've removed the MySQL tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM ingredients
WHERE ingredients_name IN ('pork', 'pepper', 'tomato', 'salt')
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct ingredients_name) = 4
```

Comment: <Nitpick>This will return false positives if an ingredient is allowed to appear more than once in a recipe (although that seems highly unlikely)</nitpick>

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Adding `ingredients_name` to the GROUP BY would fix it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @musiKk Not quite. I'd just modify the having clause to ensure I have 4 distinct ingredients:  `...HAVING COUNT(distinct ingredients_name) = 4`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, that seems reasonable. I'll have to try out sometime what the difference is.

Comment: @musiKk See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/184d6/2 for a simple example showing the difference

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Oh man, I got it completely wrong. I get it now, thanks.